# Accessing preserve_path files in a Development pod

Tags: cocoapods

Is there anyway for a podspec to generate xcconfigs to point to files in a Development Pod preserve_paths?

In a deployed pod, they're accessible via ${PODS_ROOT}, but I can't find anything comparable for a Development Pod.

${PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT} provides access in the Pod targets, but not the app targets.

Comment: Looks like the part of this PR that links to the Development Pod sandbox would need to be implemented - https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/7879